# Codeigniter. Map/reduce library

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing a website using Codeigniter and MongoDB (Alex Bilbie library).
Currently there are no support in the library to do Map/Reduce queries.

How can I do them? Is there a library for Codeigniter that supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP driver for MongoDB directly. There is a `command` function that can run any command; see examples for MapReduce here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php Also, there is a MapReduce library for PHP that makes it a bit more developer-friendly (though I've never used it): https://github.com/infynyxx/MongoDB-MapReduce-PHP/

Really, though, you might consider not using MapReduce within the context of CodeIgniter. MapReduce is better served in cron job type scenarios, where you run it once a day (or a few times a day) and build a new collection based on the results of the run (which you then query from PHP). What is your use case?

Comment: I want to count different things like how many tags the users has added (and how many for each).

Comment: I would either store the counts somewhere in the user document, and update when you add/remove tags, or have the tag counts only update every so often. Also, there is a new aggregation framework coming out for 2.2 (theoretically) that will effectively replace MapReduce for this kind of use case: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework